# Angular make alert apear again after dismissing it

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, alert

I am working on some Angular project where I add objects to a table, and not all the object's fields are valid I am presenting alerts to the user. I have the following issue: after dismissing the alerts onme time, they won't come back...
the code in html:

```
<span *ngIf="errorMessage!=null && errorMessage!=''"  name="errorSpan" class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible msg" role="alert">
  <strong>{{errorMessage}}</strong>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    </span>
```

and in TS:

```
errorMessage:string;
isWorkerValid():boolean{
    this.errorMessage="";
    if(this.workerInserted.id==null || this.workerInserted.id=="" || this.workerInserted.id.length<9 || this.workerInserted.id.length>9){
      this.errorMessage+="מספר הזהות של העובד אינו תקין"+"\n";
    }
    if(this.workerInserted.name==null || this.workerInserted.name==""){
      this.errorMessage+="שם העובד אינו תקין"+"\n";
    }    
    if(this.errorMessage!=""){
        return false;
    }         
    return true;
  }
```

I tried using `ng-show` - doesn't work for me at all! - and `dang-click="errorMessage=''"`, and so `ng-click="errorMessage=''"`
I can't use javascript in my Angular, or I think so. so I can't use things like  `$scope.hideAlert()=function(){ $scope.serverError = false; }`

as I saw in some answer here.
still, after dismissing the alert once, it won't come back the second time I ask for it.
can anyone help me???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `ng-show` `ng-click` in `Angular` 2+. `ng-show` is now `[hidden]` and `ng-click` is `(click)` but that's beyond the point.

The reason it doesn't appear anymore is that I bet when you click the `close` button, `bootstrap-4` removes the `span` from the DOM/HTML permanently.

Try wrapping it in an outside `ng-container`.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="errorMessage">
  <span name="errorSpan" 
    class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible msg" role="alert">
  <strong>{{errorMessage}}</strong>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"
       (click)="onDismissError()"
>
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    </span>
</ng-container>
....
onDismissError() {
  this.errorMessage = undefined;
}
```

This way what's inside of the `ng-container` should be repainted every time the `errorMessage` value changes.